# AngularJS Integration with Ruby on Rails using Devise

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

We are using AngularJS with Rails4, when using a custom method to update the user record, I get an error:

Here is how the controller action is defined

```
myApp.controller('AccountCtrl',..........
```

**Registering a new user works fine**

```
$scope.register = function(){
  Auth.register($scope.user).then(function(){
    $state.go('account');
  });
}
```

**Updating a User does not work**

```
$scope.update = function(){
  $scope.user = User.get({id: $stateParams.id});
  $id = $scope.user.id;
  User.update($scope.user);
}
```

**Error Message**
The error is "422 Unprocessable error from the route"

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Does anybody know what causes Angular to break the request?

Comment: Which request is breaking, the get or the put?

Comment: The next question of course is whether you get the same error if you try to set up the request manually using the `$http` service.

Comment: I mean, if you're using [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), you can't immediately use the value returned by `User.get`. You can access it in a callback function and update with `$scope.user.$save()`.

Comment: We are doing PUT--update the record.

Comment: Great, but according to the code you posted, you first `GET` the user using `User.get({id: $stateParams.id})`. That function returns an object reference which is filled in at some unspecified time in the future.

Comment: We are getting the user data by GET and then we are trying to update the user data using PUT.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the value returned by `User.get` immediately. You should process it in a callback like this:

```
$scope.update = function(){
  $scope.user = User.get({id: $stateParams.id}, function() {
    $id = $scope.user.id;
    User.update($scope.user);
  });
};
```

More examples are available [in the documentation for $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource).